# where does the url routes get resolved when you call render in rails controller actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

Is there any method that i should look at in rails3.2 source code so as to know where the navigation or the url part of the render call get resolved?
The reason is, i have a small app in which url is of the form

> www.example.com/bob/edit

the above route as it suggests renders the edit form.EDIT: i was able to get to this route by modifying response on the link_to helper.

```
def update
  #when validation passes
   redirect_to @user
  #when validation fails
  respond_to do |format|
     format.html {render :action => "edit"}
  end
end
```

Now the problem is when a validation error occurs on submission to update action of users_controller,
the url becomes

> www.example.com/users/bob/edit

config/routes.rb

```
get "users/new", to: => "users#new"
resources :users
```

as you can see there's nothing interesting happening in routes,

in models/user.rb

```
def to_param
  "#{name}"
end
```

in views/edit.html.erb

```
form_for(@user) do |f|
end
```

> **Observation:** here when the form is rendered afresh, form 'action' points to "users/bob" but when  the form is re-rendered 'cos of validation error, form action mysteriosly changes to "users/" which is weired and if i remove the to_param in user.rb model it works fine

Though its not such a big deal, i was thinking where, if i needed to override the url that is generated on render call, to change?????

Any suggestions and pointers to explore are wecome....

Comment: I guess the secound url example should be: `www.example.com/users/bob` -- you showed the same url twice.

Comment: can you post your `routes.rb`?

Comment: Seems that your form is actually putting the update to the second URL. Are you using resourceful routes ? If so is it a singular resource or a plural one ?

Comment: @jef: yeah you are right, i hadn't modified the "post" part of url generation...

Comment: The `users/:id/edit` is the standard-RESTful path to the edit method for a user instance, any reason to use an `/:id/edit` URL ?

Comment: You can remove the redundant `get "users/new", to: => "users#new"` route. This route is already created by the standard RESTful resource (`resources :users`).

Comment: i was trying to implement [link](quora.com) _eg_ [link](quora.com/bob), [link](quora.com/what-is-ruby) like urls, so messing with urls and renderers to see the best possible solution

Comment: i was trying to implement [quora.com](http://quora.com) _eg_ [quora.com/username](http://quora.com/bob), [quora.com/quesion](http://quora.com/what-is-ruby) like urls, so messing with urls and renderers to see the best possible solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're getting the URLs you're getting, but a general answer to your question would be **it doesn't**. The URL you see after sending a request is the URL the request was sent to (or redirected to), not that of the page you came from, nor that of the template you render in the end. In your case, I'm guessing the problem is that you created a custom URL for the `edit` page, but not for `update`, and your `form_for(@user)` is sending the request to your `update` URL (probably `PUT "/users/bob"`).

To fix this, the first thing is to create your custom `update` route. Maybe something like:

```rb
put ":id/update", to: => "users#update"
```

And then have your `form_for` use that URL:

```
form_for(@user, :url => "#{@user.to_param}/update")
```